# Error with function is not defined

Tags: python

I have had unexpected error message and I have no idea what is wrong with my code. Following is my code.

In class ClassA, there are two functions defined.
functionA is defined and it is for writing results on csv file.
functionA will be utilized later in functionB as part of analysis process.

However, python returns me 
**NameError: name 'functionA' is not defined**
Does anyone have any idea why?

```
class ClassA:
    def functionA(readDir, keyword, lst1, lst2):

        filename = os.path.join(readDir, keyword)
        filename = filename+'.csv'

        with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            writer=csv.writer(f)
            header=['A', 'B']
            header2=['C','D']
            writer.writerow(header)
            writer.writerows(fdist1)
            writer.writerow(header2)
            writer.writerows(fdist2)


    def functionB(self, readDir, keyword):
        lst=[]
        function1()
        function2()
        function3()
        function4() 

        fdist1, fdist2=function5() 

        functionA(readDir, keyword, fdist1, fdist2)

        return fdist1, fdist2
```

Comment: Did you mean `self.functionA`? Also, if there is no `self` argument to `functionA` it should be marked `@staticmethod`.

Comment: `functionA` is an instance method of class `ClassA`. You have to specify the object to apply it to, e.g. `self.functionA()`.

Comment: OMG ahahahahahahahahahah Thanks. My mind was somewhere in Andromeda and my eyes didn't work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**By staticmethod**

Demo:

```
class ClassA:
    @staticmethod
    def functionA():
        print "in A"

    def functionB(self, ):
        print "in B"
        ClassA.functionA()

a = ClassA()
a.functionB()
```

Output:

```
$ python csv_task.py 
in B
in A
```

---

**By instance methods**:

The most used methods in classes are instance methods, i.e instance is passed as the first argument to the method.

Demo:

```
class ClassA:
    def functionA(self):
        print "in A"

    def functionB(self, ):
        print "in B"
        self.functionA()

a = ClassA()
a.functionB()
```

Output:

```
$ python csv_task.py 
in B
in A
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to add self in front of my function. I added all of my codes, but I didn't just write self in front of that function. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @ArnoldChung: Welcome, Just take look static method, this might be useful to you in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
self.functionA(readDir, keyword, fdist1, fdist2)
```

and declare `functionA` with first argument `self` like this

```
def functionA(self, readDir, keyword, lst1, lst2):
#            ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `functionA` is part of the class `ClassA` you have to reference it via the current instance, like this:

```
self.functionA(...)
```

In your case the call would look like this:

```
self.functionA(readDir, keyword, fdist1, fdist2)
```